# How i can get html tag from component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to set addEventListener on button, this is how my component looks like

```
import { Component } from "react";

class AddPass extends Component{
    render(){
        let btn1 = document.querySelectorAll('.btn1')
        console.log(btn1)
        return <div>
            <h1>Password generator</h1>
            <input type="password" id='addPass'></input>
            <button className="btn1"></button>
            <div className="newPass"></div>
        </div>
    }
}
export default AddPass
```

this is code in index.js file

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <div className="mainDiv">
    <App/>
  </div>,
  document.querySelector(".app")
);
```

btn1 is null, and i don't know why

Comment: Please learn the basics: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be mixing native JS element methods with React as React has it's own process for updating the DOM. Here's [some documentation on how to get properly started with React](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

What you should be doing is adding listeners to the elements in the JSX and passing them handlers that can then, in your example, add changes in the input value to state, or log the state when you click the button.

Note: I've used a functional component rather than a class in this simplified example as they're a little easier to understand.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ input, setInput ] = useState('');

  function handleInput(e) {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleClick(e) {
    console.log(`Password: ${input}`);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="password" onChange={handleInput} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );

};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```